# Can a UISplitViewController be a tab within UITabViewController?

Tags: ipad, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller, subview, nib

Can I `UISplitViewController` be a tab within a `UITabViewController`.

I tried creating a new NIB with the Split View Controller configuration. And added the tab with `UISplitViewController` as the type to my mainwindow nib. I specified the NIB for the `UISplitViewController`.

Nothing happened. Can I use IB to link the `UISplitViewController` defined within my split.nib as a tab in my `mainwindow.nib`? Not sure how to set it up so that the tab controller can see the view created by the split view controller.

Answer (score 2):

Apple guidelines states that you cannot use a UISplitViewController as a child of any other controller. It must be the root view controller of your application.

In some cases, you'll get an exception if you try to do this in code (as opposed to in InterfaceBuilder)